# Creating Rails Gem with assets and backwards compatibility (before assets pipeline, < Rails 3.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, asset-pipeline

So I've read up on many guides on how to include assets in a Rails Gem. My question surrounds wanting to have backwards compatibility for my Gem. I would like to support Rails both the latest version, and Rails 3.0 and before, a time before the assets pipelines was around.

How can I have my gem place it's javascripts in the correct location (it used to be in /public/javascripts and now it should be /app/assets/javascripts).

What is the best way to detect the Rails version, and place it accordingly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Rails::VERSION::STRING
=> "3.2.13"

Rails::VERSION::MAJOR
=> 3

Rails::VERSION::MINOR
=> 2
```

In Rails 2/3.0, you can add a rails generator to copy your javascript and stylesheets to the public directory.

Whereas in Rails >= 3.1, it would be available by default in the asset folders, you can have them:

```
rails g yourgem:install
```

and write that generator to create the files in public.

Comment: Do you have an example of using generators to move javascripts for Rails 3.0 style? A link would be very appreciated.

Comment: http://edge.rubyonrails.org/generators.html works on rails 3.0 (earlier and you'll have to google)